# Attempting to set JLabel icon to image directory, null pointer exception instead

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, icons, imageicon

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:205)

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/splashscreen.jpeg")));
```

The above line is the exact line throwing the exception, and it makes me believe that the location of the file is not correct, but I have tried numerous things but to no success.

The folder structure seems to be correct, the image is within the resources folder which is within the project folder, and the folder(with the image) is next to the src folder not within. This application has to have the ability of being used offline otherwise I would just use the URL. Is there a known bug with this in the Eclipse IDE?

Figured it out. It seems that I was putting the file in the wrong location, putting it with the .class files solved the problem. Not sure if this was a proper solution or just a work around unfortunately. I had to go back to the basics .java files are compiled and the .class files are actually running, and I need to backtrack from the current working directory.

Comment: It would help to see the structure of your project.

Answer (score 1):

try this,put your image in an external folder **outside** source folder called **Images**
and after try:

```
public class Test{
public Test()
{
JFrame frame= new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Images/image.jpeg"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    Container log = login.getContentPane();
    log.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 new Test();
}
```

try to launch this app.

Comment: Tried. It didn't fix the problem, I am getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "/resources/splashscreen.jpeg" is an absolute path. Try without the leading slash or give the "real" absolute path.

Edit: I'm pretty sure the file is not found and getResource() returns null.

Why not try to get the file size? Fiddle around with this:

```
File f = new File("/resources/splashscreen.jpeg");
long length = f.length();
```

until length != 0

:-)

Comment: Unfortunately an absolute path is not a reasonable solution. I removed the leading slash to correct this and still same exception.

Comment: Ok. You get a NullPointerException. getResource() will return null if the resource is not found. So there you go.

Comment: I already knew this, I was just providing all details I possibly could.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to put "resource" folder into source folder in this case.

Comment: I tried this, still no luck same exception. Checking build path, and making sure everything looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just fiddled with the same problem and @OiRC answer helped me ALOT. I followed youtube tutorials to get code as follows:

```
ImageIcon helpIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("helpIcon.png"));
lbl_helpIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("helpIcon.png"));
lbl_helpIcon.setBounds(178, 11, 139, 62);
lbl_helpIcon.setIcon(helpIcon);
```

I kept getting a NullPointerException on

```
ImageIcon helpIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("helpIcon.png"));
```

Until I tried this

```
lbl_helpIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("helpIcon.png"));
lbl_helpIcon.setBounds(178, 11, 139, 62);
```

Worked like a charm! btw I stored my icon image like so [image: my project directory]